# polynomials in many variables and Hasse principle

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I was wondering whether there exists any result of the form

> "if $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, ..., x_k]$ is a polynomial (not form! I don't require homogeneity) of total degree $n$, with $k \geq \delta n$ for some explicit $\delta$, then $f(x) = 0$ satisfies the Hasse principle."

I'm particularly interested in the case $n = 4$. Thanks!

EDIT: I'm interested in integral solutions.

Comment: Are you interested in rational solutions or integral solutions?

Comment: Integral solutions (sorry I forgot to mention it)

Comment: Ok, this makes the problem quite a bit more difficult. Let me just mention that the answer to your question as stated is *no* (even in the case of homogeneous forms). Here the circle method is usually used to tackle such problems, and when it works it yields a bound for $k$ which his *exponential* in the degree $n$. Whereas you seem to be looking for a linear bound on the degree. Such bounds are not known in general. Of course if you are only interested in the case $n=4$, then this is not so much a problem.

Comment: My naive guess is that the circle method should be able to give the result you want when $n=4$. However you are right that people normally consider homogeneous forms as they are easier, and I don't know whether the result you want has been worked out. Have you already tried looking at the circle method literature to see if you can find the result you want?

Comment: Yes, I've tried looking at the literature a bit, but all seems geared towards forms instead of just polynomials. Do you know any references which might deal with a case similar to mine (i.e. with polys instead of forms)? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't, though I'm not an expert in the circle method. If you are feeling brave, you should try emailing some circle method experts. Its an interesting problem and I'm sure they would be receptive.

Comment: @DanielLoughran Just out of curiosity, would considering rational solutions instead of integral ones make the problem *much* easier? Do you know of any results (or similar) in the case of rational solutions? thanks again.

Comment: Yes rational solutions are much easier. This is because for such problems, the existence of a rational solution to a polynomial is equivalent to the existence of a rational solution for its homogenisation. This is of course not true in general, but the key point is that when the circle method works, it shows that if rational solutions exist then there are lots of them, namely that they are Zariski dense. So they can't all lie at infinity, so to say. Here therefore classical work of Birch should give the result you want (with exponential growth, as I explained above).

Answer (score 10):

The integral Hasse principle can fail for polynomials of degree $2$ (or $4$), even if the number of variables is huge!  For example, if $k \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$, then
$$(2x_1-1)^2 + \cdots + (2x_k-1)^2 = 1$$
has the solution $(1,1/2,\ldots,1/2)$ over $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{Z}_p$ for all odd $p$, and has a solution $(a,1,\ldots,1)$ over $\mathbf{Z}_2$ for some $a$ near $1$ by Hensel's lemma, but it has no solution over $\mathbf{Z}$ for $k>1$ since each square on the left is at least $1$.

For a much more detailed study of the integral Hasse principle, see Colliot-Thélène and Xu, 
Brauer-Manin obstruction for integral points of homogeneous spaces and representation by integral quadratic forms, *Compos. Math.* **145** (2009), no. 2, 309–363.

Comment: If $f(x,y)=0$ is a counterexample in two variables then $f(x_1+\ldots+x_n,y)=0$ is also.